# Best practise for designing REST API endpoint that accepts a nested resource POST

Tags: rest, api, api-design, data-structures, http

What's the recommended design for an endpoint that accepts a nested resource as the following:

```
POST /account

{
    "name": "Project John Doe",
    "description": "Description of the account...",
    "type": "corporate",
    "relation_number": "PR2022-1509-8",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "firstname": "John",
            "insertion": "",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "email": "john.doe@example.com",
            "phone_mobile": "1234567890",
            "phone_steady": null,
            "street": "Foo Street",
            "building_number": "12-A",
            "postal_code": "123456AB",
            "city": "Foobar",
            "country": 19,
            "priority_level": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

The requirement is that when an account is created, at least one account contact person must be present.

There are two common options, but I wonder which one should be used:

1. Creating one endpoint that accepts a POST request containg the JSON as shown above. Thus, accepting a nested object.
2. Creating two endpoints, `POST /account` and `POST /account/contact`
   The client is responsible for creating an account in one request, and then create a contact person using a second request. Some sources on the internet suggest to take this approach.
   But, when a client just doesn't/couldn't send that second POST request to create a contact person for the just created account, the data is inconsistent.

How should this be designed **to comply with the guidelines**?

Comment: would an account ever be created with more than one contact, or is it always exactly one?

Comment: At least one contact, it is allowed to create it with multiple contacts.

Comment: REST principles do not provide any guidance on this (i.e. REST is entirely agnostic about the nature and the semantics of your resources).  Since this is a matter of semantics, it all comes down to whatever works best for the users/consumers of your API.

Comment: The second option is cleaner in my opinion. To mitigate the issue you mentioned (about data inconsistency), you should only commit once the second request has successfully completed, or perform a rollback if it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't so much which one to choose but that the two solutions conflict.

ie. if I post to account with the contact list then I overwrite (possibly delete entirely?) the relationship with existing contacts which may have changed since I got my copy of account.

My advice would be to avoid the nested object and represent the relationship with just IDs. eg

```
account
{
    "Id": "a"
    "name": "Project John Doe",
    "description": "Description of the account...",
    "type": "corporate",
    "relation_number": "PR2022-1509-8",
}

contact
{
    "Id": "b"
    "AccountId":"a"
}
```

Now as long as I accept non existing account ids on Contact, I can upsert both account and contact to their own endpoints, following whatever RESTful URLs and methods you feel best.

Plus you can get big lists of accounts without sending all the unneeded contacts.